# Image cache and management on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, uiimageview, nsdata

I have a json file which it's body is an image in form of binary(NSData).
I download it and convert it to an image using:

```
    [cell.imgPhoto setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

And load it to an image view into a cell. I have two major problem. First is downloading an image several times and second is caching. I can't change server side codes and I have to work with that! I emphasize on downloading in form of json and it's body is an image.

How can I do it or is there any component to automate it for me?

Comment: images are cached for you already (they are only stored in memory as long as the app remains active and doesn't receive a signal from the OS to quit). you need to save them using some persistent storage method after that. your url requests are cached as well for somewhere between 6-24 hours by default if your response headers don't contain an expiration tag, and if they do they expire when the tag indicates. lastly, what issue are you having with downloading multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

check following libraries, https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache/ , both provide caching support..

Comment: Yes but none of them works with nsdata. They only can process URLs like site.com/images/img1.png